# Prevent UICellView fom adjusting it's height automatically

Tags: ios, interface-builder

This is weird. Look at my IB project first:

[image: IB project]

And now how it looks on the simulator:

[image: simulator screenshoot before scrolling]

Two things here:

1. Why is the cell higher than I set on the IB? I swear there is no code messing up with it's frame. I'm using auto layout.
2. I'm changing Green label's frame when I fill it with text. Actually there is another line after GGTP,... but it appears only after I scroll the list down so this elements dissapears and then scroll back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using auto layout. In new version of xcode, auto layout is default. You can uncheck "Use auto-layout" in the view's File inspector tab.

Then, you can specify cell's heigh by overwrite this method in table view controller.

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 70.0; // specify table cell's height
}
```

Comment: Well, if I uncheck it the "label refreshing" problem is gone, but the cell is still same size

Comment: Then you can modify the cell in Size inspector tab.

Comment: I did. It look like on the project, but when I run it it streetches